# node.js - How do we send a "user-initiated" email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, fuel-sdk, node.js, node-salesforce

I can create a Triggered email and send it to lists. In addition to sending a triggered email, I need to send "user-initiated" email, or an email to a list.

Apparently sending a user-initiated email is impossible with rest.
so maybe we can do this with fuel-soap?

Here is a successful soap retrieve (this works)

```
mcloudTools.testSoap = function() {

    var options = {
        filter: {
            leftOperand: 'Name',
            operator: 'equals',
            rightOperand: 'test'
        }
    };

    return new BPromise(function(fulfill, reject) {

        mcloudTools.IET_Client.SoapClient.retrieve(
            'Email',   //Object types: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/
            ["ID", "Name", "Subject", "CategoryID", "EmailType"],
            options,
            function( err, response ) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    fulfill(response);
                }
            }
        );

    });
};
```

Here is an attempt at a soap perform (this is where I need help).
It looks like soap "Perform" is not an option in fuel-soap.

[Using Node.js: What would be the best contribution to the fuel-soap library if I want to send an email (other than a triggered email)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132322/using-node-js-what-would-be-the-best-contribution-to-the-fuel-soap-library-if-i)

```
mcloudTools.sendEmailSoap = function() {
    console.log('mcloudTools.sendEmailSoap');

    var options = {
        props: {
            "Action": "start"
            , "CustomerKey": "2177425"
            , "SenderProfile": {
                "FromName": "FromName"
                , "FromAddress": "send@cvstest.com"
            }
        }
    };

    return new BPromise(function(fulfill, reject) {

        mcloudTools.IET_Client.SoapClient.perform(
            'EmailSendDefinition',   //Object types: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/
            options,
            function( err, response ) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    fulfill(response);
                }
            }
        );
    });
};
```

How can you send an EmailDefinition using node.js (not a trigger email, a user-initiated email).

Comment: That's one hell of a long question

Comment: @DavidMadison, can you [edit] this into a shorter question?

Comment: I shortened it. It may be irrelevant, looks like you can't do much from node.js. fuel-soap and fuel-rest are limited. No soap perform available so you can't send an email to a list. All you can do apparently is send a Trigger email, which doesn't have the tracking that we need.