# Using Node.js: What would be the best contribution to the fuel-soap library if I want to send an email (other than a triggered email)

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, fuel-sdk, node.js

Using Node.js: What would be the best contribution to the fuel-soap library if I want to send an email (other than a triggered email) such as a user-initialted email or just an email send to a list?

Looking at fuel-soap, these are the soap methods implemented:

- handles the Create SOAP Action
- handles the Retrieve SOAP Action
- handles the Update SOAP Action
- handles the Delete SOAP Action
- handles the Describe SOAP Action
- handles the Execute SOAP Action

It looks like the Send Object is what we need to implement "Used to send email and retrieve aggregate data based on a JobID."

I would need to prototype new functionality into fuel-soap in order to use “Perform"

The send object uses:

1. Create - Creates an individual object or a batch of objects.
2. Delete - Deletes an individual object or a batch of objects.
3. Perform - Method description goes here.
4. Retrieve - Retrieves an individual object or a batch of objects.
5. Update - Updates an individual object or a batch of objects.

Background:

Using Node.js, I would like to send a User-Initiated email. The only option under "apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/messaging/“ is POST & GET for “messageDefinitionSends”.

messageDefinitionSends = "Sends transactional email using Marketing Cloud's triggered send functionality”.

So the only send functionality available for rest is "Triggered Sends”. It works fine, sends a triggered email, I get “Queued”.

Under Tracking > Sends, the triggered sends are aggregated so this is not the type of email we want to send. The user-initiated send has the tracking per email, this is what we need.

So rest is a dead end. Lets move to soap.

The routes available in FuelSDK-Node are:
- routes/campaign-routes.js
- routes/contentarea-routes.js
- routes/de-routes.js
- routes/email-routes.js
- routes/folder-routes.js
- routes/index-routes.js
- routes/list-routes.js
- routes/main.js
- routes/rest-routes.js
- routes/sms-routes.js
- routes/soap-routes.js
- routes/subscriber-routes.js
- routes/tracking-routes.js
- routes/triggeredsend-routes.js

The only send functionality is “sendTriggeredSend” under routes/triggeredsend-routes.js. So back to my original question: What would be the best contribution to the fuel-soap library if I want to send an email (other than a triggered email) such as a user-initialted email or just an email send to a list?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**You can check it.**

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Node-SOAP

This library allows users access to the Salesforce Marketing Cloud (formerly ExactTarget) SOAP API at a low level.